# Multiple onchange events in same modal box not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I have onchange events in one modal but it is not getting executed when I am trying to do that. And I have more than one modal in same page but only the first modal is getting opened. I have tried this code:

PHP Code:

```
 $n1="SELECT * FROM country WHERE id='".$row['id']."'";
 $n=$conn->query($n1);
 $nrow=$n->fetch_assoc();
```

HTML Code for the drop down list:

```
<label class="control-label col-md-2">Type</label>
 <div class="col-md-3 ">
      <select  class="form-control" name="type" id="type<?php $row['id'];?>" required>
  <?php

 echo '<option value="'.'outside'.'">'.'outside'.'</option>';
 $sq2="SELECT state_intcode,CONCAT(state_cat,'-', state_name) AS p FROM state WHERE state_intcode='".$nrow['state_f']."'";
 $re2=$conn->query($sq2);
 while ($ro2 = $re2->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<option value="'.$ro2['state_intcode'].'" >'.$ro2['p'].'</option>';
   }?>
   </select>
        </div>
```

When I selected any option from the drop down list should bring the onchange event on the following field.

```
<label class="control-label col-md-3">Category</label>
  <div class="col-md-3 ">
          <select  class="form-control" name="place" id="place<?php $row['id'];?>" required></select>
  </div>
```

Following is the javascript for the onchange event:

```
$("#type").change(function()
 {
   var id=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;
    console.log(id);
    if (id=="outside")
    {
        $.ajax
    ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "country_edit_ajax.php",
    data:{id: id, 
          out :1,
          },
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#place").html(html);
    } 
    });
    }
    else
    {
    $.ajax
    ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "country_edit_ajax.php",
    data: {id: id, 
          in :1,
          },
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#place").html(html);
    } 
    });
    }
```

This is the country_edit_ajax.php:

```
if($_POST['in'])
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM place WHERE place_type='$id'";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
{
$id=$row['place_intcode'];
$data=$row['place_name'];
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
}
}
if($_POST['out'])
{
$sql1="SELECT * FROM state WHERE state_cat='out'";
$result1=$conn->query($sql1);
while($row1=$result1->fetch_assoc())
{
$id=$row1['state_intcode'];
$data=$row1['state_name'];
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
}
}
```

Comment: `id="type<?php $row['id'];?>"` and `id="place<?php $row['id'];?>"` are not going to match `'#type'` and `'#place'` if the ids are not empty strings

Comment: First, you better format your code; there are not many people who will waste their time reading this wall of brackets. On topic: you may try to replace your `#type` selector with `[id^=type]`